# How to migrate entire gitlab project?

Tags: gitlab, migration, backup

I want to migrate the group, all sub-groups and projects from gitlab.com to a self contained gitlab instance(local). I can migrate the group and sub-groups but not the projects.

The documentation says this, but I'm not able to 100% understand it:

> On self-managed GitLab, migrating project resources are not available by default. To make them available, ask an administrator to enable the feature flag named bulk_import_projects. On GitLab.com, migrating project resources are not available.

link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#migrated-project-resources

This means that I can't migrate from gitlab.com to self contained gitlab?

Is there an automated method that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a self-managed instance of GitLab, and you have administrator rights (or rather the ability to access the rails console), then you can follow the instructions in [documentation you linked to](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#migrated-project-resources).

Basically, you need to [turn on the feature flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html#how-to-enable-and-disable-features-behind-flags) by starting the [rails console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/rails_console.html#starting-a-rails-console-session), and running the command:

`Feature.enable(:bulk_import_projects)`

After turning on the feature flag, and you go to [migrate a group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/index.html#select-the-groups-to-import), it should migrate the projects in the group as well.

There is no built-in automation to import all of your groups. If you need to, you might consider looking at the [Congregate tool mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/index.html#automate-group-and-project-import).

Answer (score 0):

Note: with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#direct-transfer-migration-on-gitlab-self-managed-no-longer-requires-feature-flag) (March 2023), this is easier:

> ### Direct transfer migration on GitLab self-managed no longer requires feature flag
>
> The [open beta release of migrating GitLab projects](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/01/18/try-out-new-way-to-migrate-projects/) with top-level groups by direct transfer meant GitLab self-managed users gained access to the beta feature.
> However, instance administrators had to enable both:
>
> - An application setting for migrating groups.
> - The `bulk_import_projects` feature flag for migrating projects in the groups.
>
> In this release, we have removed the feature flag so you only need the [application setting](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#enable-migration-of-groups-and-projects-by-direct-transfer).
>
> This change also enables GitLab Dedicated instances to take advantage of the feature.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#migrate-groups-by-direct-transfer-recommended) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/339941).

And, still with [GitLab 15.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/03/22/gitlab-15-10-released/#improved-import-error-messages-that-include-subrelation-errors) (March 2023):

> ### Improved import error messages that include subrelation errors
>
> When migrating GitLab groups and projects, errors listed as import failures on the group **Import history** page were not always informative enough.
>
> We now include errors from all nested subrelations to make it clear why a relation (for example, a merge request), failed to import.
> Better error messages support debugging and speed up resolution time.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/import/#group-import-history) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/387782).

---

See [GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#better-error-message-when-direct-transfer-setting-is-disabled) (April 2023)

> ### Better error message when direct transfer setting is disabled
>
> GitLab group and project migration by direct transfer requires that both GitLab instances have the feature enabled in application settings by an instance administrator.
>
> Until now, if you tried to initiate an import when the feature was disabled on the source instance, you received a `404` error.
>
> We’ve replaced the `404` error with an informative message, and provided guidance on how to enable the feature.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/visibility_and_access_controls.html#enable-migration-of-groups-and-projects-by-direct-transfer) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/388093).